# How to restrict Android device to not open some specific site e.g.youtube, facebook

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application for Android devices, Now I want to implement the functionality that if my application is installed on the device  than it is restricted to open youtube or facebook.

Because this application is for employees and my client do not want that his emplyees waste their time in youtube or facebook. I tried to find some help on google but received no good source.

thanks

Comment: Couldn't the user just uninstall that application then?

Comment: What about installing another webbrowser/facebook/youtube app? Users getting creative :-)

Comment: @Lasse ... yes it can but then he will lose the saved data and he has to answer about it. He can make some excuse about it one or two times but not daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but you could try creating entries in the `/etc/hosts` file of the device to redirect the user to another destination. You/your app will need root privileges to edit the file.

Beside the webbrowser(s), don't forget to check if it's possible to use the facebook and youtube apps from the market.