# How to make entries in Android /etc/hosts file to restrict specific websites

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict Android device to not open some specific site e.g.youtube, facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531627/how-to-restrict-android-device-to-not-open-some-specific-site-e-g-youtube-facebo)

I am developing an application where a feature is to stop users to use YouTube or facebook while they are using the application. By some finding I came to know that I have to edit **/etc/hosts** .... but how ... thats what I want to know...

some one told me to make entries in this file to restrict specific websites but for that I need root privileges.

Comment: Are you aware that this requires the device to be rooted?

Comment: If you are using the a rooted device or the emulator, just follow this tutorial: http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-how-to-test-local-web-apps-on-an-emulated-device-avd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to edit the **/etc/hosts** files from application code (code that is installed from the market or on a device that hasn't been rooted).

If the device has been rooted then you could just `su` and then write new data to it, but on a production device you won't have the necessary permission.

EDIT: what may make more sense (and I don't know how easy/difficult this will be in practice) is to use a custom DNS server that resolves IP addresses you want to ban. If you log in with `adb shell` you can run **getprop** which will list all the parameters. Find the DNS parameters and then do **setprop {dns parameter name} {new dns ip}** where you point to a dns server you control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've heard about something like [this](http://pocketnow.com/tweaks-hacks/how-to-surf-faster-on-your-android-using-the-hosts-table), which suggests a way to block ad hosts by setting their IP address to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.

The page does say to reboot, but not sure if this is for *changes* to the file, or rather for when you *create* the file in the first place. I would guess the latter. Normally changes to /etc/hosts are picked up dynamically.

Whether you can update the hosts file from application code, I have no idea.