# How to kill Android process if user opens youtube

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restrict Android device to not open some specific site e.g.youtube, facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531627/how-to-restrict-android-device-to-not-open-some-specific-site-e-g-youtube-facebo)

I am writing an application and a feature is that if the user opens youtube.com then not allow him to do this.

So I planned to kill the Android process if the user try to open it. I know that this code kills the process

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

but How can I get pid(process id) of process if it open youtube. The problem is to get process id which opens youtube.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039398/android-get-pid-of-other-applications

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

Comment: Good luck keeping up with those guys: http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=youtube+proxy&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 Also, that *other* tube site is ok to open?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am writing an application and a feature is that if the user opens youtube.com then not allow him to do this.

Fortunately, malware authors have limited ability to do things like this.

> So I planned to kill the Android browser process if the user try to open it.

Fortunately, this is impossible, at least on Android 2.1+.

> I know that this code kills the process

Only if you have rights to kill that process. Fortunately, you do not have rights to kill that process.

Comment: Lols and +1 for you Fortunate's

Comment: What if my application registers as administrator application

Comment: @Azhar: If by "administrator application", you mean to use the device admin APIs, then you can use the device admin APIs. None of them let you terminate a foreign process either, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a webview they are opening the url in then you could use the `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` this gives the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.

example:

```
WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
{
   // Override page
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
   {
        // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
        if ( url.contains("youtube") == true )
            //Load new URL & override URL Link
            return true;

        // Return false to not override url loading.
        return false;
   }
};
```