# how to kill other process or use adb command line in app

Tags: android, adb, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using Nexus 6p and Android Oreo.

How to kill other process or use adb command line in app?

Is that possible at root?

---

Comment: What are you asking? Are you trying to get an ADB shell on the device, or are you asking how to use root to kill other apps?

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm asking two ways. how to kill other process in my android application or how to use adb command line in my android application. thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can not kill other process if has no system or root permission.
please check [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535086/how-to-kill-android-process-if-user-opens-youtube/6535201#6535201) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245138/kill-other-process-in-android)

Comment: Thank you. solved this problem with device rooting. so i'm using adb command in my android application.

Comment: So can you choose my answer?